# Using FindSecBugs in Maven throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory, spotbugs, find-sec-bugs

I'm new to Maven.I'm using **Mac OSX**. I tried to build the project using maven and it happened properly. Then I used **mvn spotbugs:spotbugs** to use the spotbugs plugin! It took a while and threw Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

The project I tried is 330 MB which is quite big and I can do nothing about it for now.I tried many solutions online:

1.export `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"` (I tried increasing upto 12000m still wasn't working)

2.Used this plugin

```
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <meminitial>1024m</meminitial>
            <maxmem>8096m</maxmem>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

and still didn't work.

Can anybody guide me through it? I'm using maven spotbugs version 3.1.12.

Using **java 11,Maven 3**

Answer (score 1):

The SpotBugs Maven Plugin has "[How do I avoid OutOfMemory errors?](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/faq.html#How_do_I_avoid_OutOfMemory_errors)" in its FAQ which I assume you have seen *(since you tried `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"`)*

But there is one more thing there

> You can also use the fork option which will for a new JVM. You then use the maxHeap option to control the heap size.

Looking at the [docs](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/spotbugs-mojo.html#fork) is seams in `3.1.12.3-SNAPSHOT` the `fork` option is `true` by default. If that is the case for `3.1.12` (or whatever is the exact version you use) and if I'm reading the docs correctly, then you have to configure the `maxHeap` which [defaults to 512](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/spotbugs-mojo.html#maxHeap).

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above, try adjusting the maxHeap value.

what follows is a snippet of maven configuration. this was how i configured spotbugs in order to avoid the out of memory error.

```
 <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spotbugs-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <maxHeap>2048</maxHeap>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```